# Plotting in Python's Brian library - blank plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a python library named Brian to do a simple simulation. In Brian I have one plot using two subplots that are displayed using

```
brian.show()
```

from internally calculated data.

When using my old laptop, the plots work fine, but when I run the unaltered script on a new laptop with a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04, I only get a blank plot.

I used pip to install numpy, scipy, matplotlib, sympy, and I used apt-get / aptitude to install their dependencies.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have no idea what `brian` is, but you likely need to configure matplotlib to use an interactive backend. plenty of info on SO and the web about choosing backends for matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem actually.

On the old computer I had matplotlib 1.4.0 installed, on the new on I had 1.4.2.

I reverted to 1.4.0 on the new one and it works!